# Limiting access to a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I am using Google Forms for yearbook quotes and need to only allow the seniors to  use the form/ The form is posted on our web page however all of the grade levels have Google accounts. Can I put specifics on the log in?

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms by itself has not a way to limit access by groups of the same domain. You should keep the link for respondents "secret".

One alternative is to create a group including all the seniors. The group could be created by one of the Google Apps domain administrators, by any allowed to create groups through Google Group for Business (it's include in Google Apps for Education) or by using the consumer version of Google Groups.

Then you could use that group:

1. to send the link for the form respondents
2. to post the link to a Google Doc and use the seniors group to share the doc with them
3. to create a Google Site and use the seniors group to share the site or a page with them.